# Get a day of a week filled automatically to a new column with a WEEKDAY function MySQL

Tags: mysql, autofill, weekday

I am stuck on a problem I have with MySQL, I am quite new to it so please have patience :D. I have a table that includes a column with specific dates (each date has multiple entries) and I would like to create a new column with a specific day (Monday, Tuesday, etc.) based on the date I already have. I found a function WEEKDAY I would like to use, but I can't find a way to update all the rows automatically.

I already ADD COLUMN "day" (which is empty now) and need to add the values for all rows. The table has a thousand rows so there is no way I would do it manually one by one. I am sure there is a way around doing it by SQL code. Would appreciate it if anyone can give me a hint.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add table definition, It's not generally a good idea to store easily derived data but if you must then review UPDATE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html and post code if you get into difficulty. Can date column change? If so consider a trigger to update weekday column https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html also consider generated columns https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: Ps WEEKDAY returns a day number if you want a name https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname